# provide data and call function from importer package

Tags: go

I have 2 module from my `go` project, `packageA` and `packageB`. And my `packageA` import `packageB`:

```golang
///inside packageA:

var pb = packageB.PackageB{}

///so that I can use packageB function

pb.DoTask()
...
```

Is there a way for `packageB` to send the processed data or call `packageA` function after the process is done?

I cannot use:

```golang
///inside packageA:

data = pb.DoTask()
```

because some of `packageB` task is cronjobs with various interval. The best way will be for `packageB` to call `packageA` function and pass the data once they are done.

I tried:

```golang
///inside packageB:

var pa = packageA.PackageA{}
```

but got the compiled error:

> import cycle not allowed

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your `pb.DoTask()` can return `channel`, and `packageA` can read the data from channel later.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT have cyclic dependency, package A importing Package B and vice versa. If Package B runs long running task then it needs a way to notify task runners after the task is completed. Either by callback or channel.

Here is one simple way of callback

A Package B (task in my case) that runs long running task:

```
package task

import "time"

type Task struct {
}

type Result struct {
    status string
}
type Notify func(Result)

func (t *Task) PerformAndNotify(notify Notify) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)//simulate long running task
    notify(Result{status: "Success"})
}
```

And now in main package that will import task package and wait for execution until it is notified of result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sample/task"
)

func main() {
    t := task.Task{}
    t.PerformAndNotify(func(result task.Result) {
        fmt.Println(result)
    })
}
```